# Circuitikz transmission gate (Bowtie symbol)

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, circuits, tikz-circuit-lib

After reading the manual following question remained unanswered: Is there a transmission gate symbol (the one on the right) built into tikz/circuitikz?

If not, is there an extension providing the node? How would someone include such a node for use in tikz/circuitikz?

[image: Transmission gate symbols]

Comment: page 18 of the manual is what you are looking for -- http://kebo.pens.ac.id/CTAN/graphics/circuit_macros/doc/CMman.pdf -- the `tgate` needs to be rotated--  how to use it  will require someone with more experience than me

Comment: If you plan to use it a lot, one can create the symbol.  You need to think about the relative size and anchor names, and whether to make it a bipole (with extra anchors) or only a node.

Comment: As said by @JohnKormylo --- if you want you can open a component request on https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues --- specifying more thing like relative default size (for example w/ respect to a logic gate, or a MOSFET, or whatever fits better), what must be filled if the symbol has to be filled, if it's main use is as a bipole or as a node component... no promises, but sometimes I have a bit of spare time... ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### update

Since release 1.2.4 (unreleased now, but soon to come) you can use the [new `tgate` and `double tgate` components:](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/445)

[image]

...also in path-style version:

[image]

#### old answer

Really there is no such a symbol in `circuitikz` --- you can make a request on the issue tracker but it will be after 1.0, I suspect.

The nice thing is that you can quite build it with the new `muxdemux` shape (version 1.0.0-pre2 or better):

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[
    simple triangle/.style={muxdemux, muxdemux def={
            NL=1, NR=1, NB=1, NT=1, w=2, Lh=2, Rh=0,
            },
        }
    ]
    \draw (0,0) node[simple triangle, anchor=left, no input leads](LtoR){}
                (LtoR.right) node[simple triangle, xscale=-1, anchor=left](RtoL) {};
                \node [ocirc] at ([yshift=.5ex]LtoR.btpin 1) {};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

you need to adjust manually the position of the not symbol, but the result is quite nice:

[image: output of the code snippet above]

Comment: Very good...and good work.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastiano!