# How to draw the symbol for a valve?

Tags: circuitikz

[image]

Anyone who can help me write the latex for this symbol? I'm having a hard time doing the valve symbol.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/526807/197451

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SE. Is this some standard electrical circuit symbol? If yes, you can ask for a feature in https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues , and I'll see when I have time what I can do. Otherwise, if it's a special/spot-on symbol, the best thing is to draw it in Ti*k*Z (maybe into a `pic`) which is quite easy...